# How to set first value as selected to SELECT(multiple) using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working to populate first value selected in SELECT(multiple) using angular js

```
<select multiple="multiple" ng-model="selectedCatMarkets"> <option value="{{market.marketCode}}" ng-repeat="market in markets">{{market.marketName}}</option> </select>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.markets = [{  "marketName": "US", "marketCode": "29" }, { "marketName": "Test Market2", "marketCode": "30" }, { "marketName": "TestMarket3", "marketCode": "31" }];
```

Can anybody suggest me, how I can show the first value selected by default on page load. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-options` - then set your model equal to the first option:

```
<select ng-options="market.marketCode as market.marketName for market in markets" multiple="multiple" ng-model="selectedCatMarkets"></select>
```

JS:

```
$scope.selectedCatMarkets = markets[0];
```

Comment: the code I have written, is being used through out the project and it would be difficult to replace with ng-options. Can you suggest any solution based on my approach?